# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '(' in

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I get this error message when I trying to validate a username. The following pregexp string is this: `^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z_-]*[\w_-]*[\S]$|^([a-zA-Z])[0-9_-]*[\S]$|^[a-zA-Z]*[\S]$^`. I have tried everything I can think of, but nothing works.

These are the following possible solutions I have tried, but fails:

```
^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z_-]*[\/w_-]*[\/S]$|^([a-zA-Z])[0-9_-]*[\/S]$|^[a-zA-Z]*[\/S]$^
/^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z_-]*[\/w_-]*[\/S]$|^([a-zA-Z])[0-9_-]*[\/S]$|^[a-zA-Z]*[\/S]$^/
~^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z_-]*[\/w_-]*[\/S]$|^([a-zA-Z])[0-9_-]*[\/S]$|^[a-zA-Z]*[\/S]$^~
#^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z_-]*[\/w_-]*[\/S]$|^([a-zA-Z])[0-9_-]*[\/S]$|^[a-zA-Z]*[\/S]$^#
```

I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Negin: Read the question title.

Comment: what do you want allowable in a username?

Comment: Lol! sorry! I didn't mentioned it is a warning I just mentioned the function

Comment: It only validates usernames like `AaaaaaS`

Comment: if you want some with underlines and number I can put it for you.please tell us what do you want exactly as accept ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression starts with a `^`, so this is being interpreted as a **[delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)**.

A number of characters later, your regular expression then contains a `^` within it, and since this is unescaped, it is being interpreted as the end of the pattern part of the regular expression.

Immediately after the second `^`, your regular expression then contains a `(`.  In preg_match, anything after the closing delimiter is interpreted as a **[modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)**, and `(` is not a modifier.

To fix it, you need to [read the PHP manual page on delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

I would assume you want something like this:

```
/^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z_-]*[\w_-]*[\S]$|^([a-zA-Z])[0-9_-]*[\S]$|^[a-zA-Z]*[\S]$/
```

In your first example, it looks like you've forgotten to add any delimiters, and the `^` was not intended as a delimiter.  In the subsequent examples where you have added delimiters, you haven't told us what the problems with those are (maybe they should be different questions?).

Answer (score -1):

```
 #^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z_-]*[\/w_-]*[\/S]$|^([a-zA-Z])[0-9_-]*[\/S]$|^[a-zA-Z]*[\/S]$^#
```

The problem you have is with `[\/S]`. This forces the usernames to end in `S` or a forward `/` slash. You meant to write `[\S]` there. (Albeit I'm not sure what the purpose of that is. That would allow *any* non-space character at the end.)